# mysql query return only one post

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to  fetch all data by  id , my Id  is 149 and 3 post asign with this id . but I am getting only one post here .

```
SELECT * FROM pages WHERE rel_blog IN (149) and page_category='auspicious' order by add_date desc limit 7
```

Exact code  is

```
        <?php

        $get_id = "select rel_blog from pages";
        //TRIM(username) AS username
        $get_id;
        $resu = mysql_query($get_id);
        $p_id="";
        $rel_b="";
        $i = 1;
        while ($page_id = mysql_fetch_array($resu)){

           $p_id.= $page_id['page_id']; 
           $rel_b.= $page_id['rel_blog']; 
         //echo $rel_b   
          } 
        $p_id."<br>";
        $k=ltrim($rel_b,',');
       // echo $k;
       // echo $rel_b."<br>";

        echo  $getblog = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE rel_blog IN ($k) and page_category='auspicious' order by add_date desc limit 7";
        //echo $getblog;

?>
```

I am trying to fetch data by top written query 
[image]

Comment: `LIMIT 7` does not guarantee that you will get 7 records, it only guarantees that you _won't_ get more than 7.

Comment: In your query it is you are using `149` and in question you have provided `144`

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen@problem is that I am getting only one  post , while 3 post assign with this id

Comment: Mittal @my mistake , its  149 i will change this

Comment: Check the page_category for all 3 post? Does it 'auspicious' for all?

Comment: And what about page category. How you expect a answer in case we can see a data?

Comment: Mittal @yes  page category for all , please let me know how can i used group by in this query ,  IN operator  consider only one data, if id is change , like 140 and  150 its return all data , but id is same 140 and  140 then its return only one

Comment: Just add some sample and expected data to this question.

Comment: cdaiga@see updated question i  attached screenshot, I want fetch data  my  id is same for both post like category name

Comment: Any budy know how can get all data with same id  With IN operators  or any alternate solution

Comment: **The `mysql` PHP extension is dead** -- Stop using the [`mysql_*()` PHP functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). They are old, deprecated since PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO_mysql`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead. Read the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/4265352) to learn more about why and how.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
while ($page_id = mysql_fetch_array($resu)){    
    $p_id.= $page_id['page_id']; 
    $rel_b.= $page_id['rel_blog']; 
} 
$p_id."<br>";
$k=ltrim($rel_b,',');
```

You are concatenating the string `$rel_b` inside while loop. The value of `$rel_b` will be eg; 145147149

You should also concatenate with "," like this and try again

```
$rel_b.= $page_id['rel_blog'] . ",";
```